# How do I receive cookies on my website without the sameSite attribute giving me undefined or also the domain is invalid

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, next.js, setcookie

When I make the request to the server using axios and adding credentials in true

```
import axios from "axios";

const httpService = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL,
});

export default httpService;
```

```
const sendCredentials = async (formData) =\> {
try {
const response = await httpService.post("/login", formData, {
withCredentials: true,
});
return response.data;

} catch (error) {
if (error) {
return error;
}
}
};
```

my server, which is configured as follows:

```
const express = require("express");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const cors = require("cors");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");

const sequelize = require("./database/database");

require("./models/User");
require("./models/Role");
require("./models/Product");
require("./models/Purchase");
require("./models/ProductImage");
require("./models/PurchaseProduct");

const userRoutes = require("./routes/users.routes");
const authRoutes = require("./routes/auth.routes");
const productRoutes = require("./routes/products.routes");
const purchaseRoutes = require("./routes/purchases.routes");
const telegramRoutes = require("./routes/telegram.routes");
const config = require("./config");
const createRoles = require("./libs/initialSetup");

createRoles();

const app = express();
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: [config.origin.client],
    credentials: true,
  })
);

app.use(morgan("dev")); 
app.use(express.json());

app.use(userRoutes);
app.use(authRoutes);
app.use(productRoutes);
app.use(purchaseRoutes);
app.use(telegramRoutes);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;

async function main() {
  try {
    await sequelize.sync({ alter: true, logging: false });

    app.listen(PORT, () => {
      console.log(`Server listening on ${PORT}`);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Unable to connect to the database:", error);
  }
}

main();
```

receives the request and executes the following action through the "/login" route:

```
const login = async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  const user = await User.findOne({
    where: {
      email,
    },
    include: [Role],
  });

  if (!user) {
    return res.status(401).json({ error: "User not found" });
  } 
  const storedHashedPassword = user.password;

  const isPasswordMatch = await compare(password, storedHashedPassword);

  if (!isPasswordMatch) {
    return res.status(401).json({ error: "Invalid credentials" });
  }

  const token = sign(
    {
      exp: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * 60 * 24 * 30,
      id: user.id,
      email: user.email,
      username: user.name,
    },
    config.secretSignJwt
  );

  const serialized = serialize("myTokenName", token, {
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: true,
    sameSite: "lax",
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30,
    domain: "kids-ecommerce.vercel.app",
    path: "/",
  });

  res.cookie(serialized);
  res.json("succesfull");
};
```

then in the browser I am correctly receiving the response with a status of 200, where I can obtain the cookie and other data, but the sameSite attribute comes with the value Lax=undefined and the domain appears as not allowed, for this reason I cannot set it as a cookie.

Here I give you more details of the server response registered in the browser:

```
Request URL:  https://e-commerce-backend-self.vercel.app/login
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200
Remote Address: 76.76.21.93:443
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Response Headers:
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://kids-ecommerce.vercel.app
Cache-Control: public, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Length: 12
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Fri, 28 Jul 2023 16:18:01 GMT
Etag: W/"c-pW/4RryX/+LCeLkf5W6sZxG5ayI"
Server: Vercel
Set-Cookie: myTokenName=eyJhbGciOJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAijE2OTMxNTMwODEsImlkIjoNmZhMWRlN2YtYWkYy00MzRiLWIzYmQtZTMxYWE5YTViM2Y3IiwiZW1haWwiOiJyaXNiZWw5NjEwMTlAZ21haWwuY29tIiwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJSaXNiZWwiLCJpYQiOjE2OTA1NjEwODF9.bEz37GzE4UoXRONn_P_FgkjhlZ93NjCta0Tsd0C_RQ; Max-Age=2592000000; Domain=kids-ecommerce.vercel.app; Path=/; Secure; SameSite=Lax=undefined; Path=/
```

All I want is for the browser to stop warning me this:

(
Some cookies are misusing the recommended attribute "SameSite"
Value "SameSite" is not valid for cookie "myTokenName". The supported values ​​are: “Lax”, “Strict”, “None”.
The cookie "myTokenName" does not have a proper "SameSite" attribute value. Soon, cookies without the "SameSite" attribute or with an invalid value will be treated as "Lax". This means that the cookie was no longer sent in third-party contexts. If your application depends on this cookie being available in such contexts, add the attribute “SameSite=none“. To know more about the “SameSite” attribute, read https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite

The cookie “myTokenName” has been rejected by an invalid domain.
)

and correctly set the cookie.

I would really appreciate the community if you could help me with this issue...